# How to separate a linked list by a predicate in python?

Tags: python, linked-list, iteration

I want to define a iterative function named separate; it is passed one linked list and a predicate; it returns a 2-tuple of two linked lists: the first is a linked list of all the values in the parameter where the predicate returns True; the second is a linked list of all the values in the parameter where the predicate returns False; the values in each list must be the reverse of their order in the parameter linked list.

There is my code:

```
class LN:
def __init__(self,value,next=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next  = next
```

#

```
def list_to_ll(l):
    if l == []:
        return None
    front = rear = LN(l[0])
    for v in l[1:]:
        rear.next = LN(v)
        rear = rear.next
    return front

def str_ll(ll):
    answer = ''
    while ll != None:
        answer += str(ll.value)+'->'
        ll = ll.next
    return answer + 'None'
```

Eg:

```
ll = list_to_ll([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
even,odd = separate(ll,lambda x : x%2 == 0)
print(str_ll(even)+' and '+str_ll(odd))
```

I should get:

```
8->6->4->2->0 and 9->7->5->3->1
```

This is my separate function:

```
def separate(ll,p):

    if ll == None:
        return (None,None)
    else:
        while ll != None:
            a = ll.value
            ll = ll.next
            if ll != None:
                b = ll.value
            else:
                b = None        
            if p(a):
                T = LN(a,b)
                a = b
            if not p(a):
                F = LN(a,b)
                a = b

        return (T,F)
```

It raise AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'. How can I do to fix that?

Comment: Would you mind telling us what line causes the error?

Comment: print(str_ll(even)+' and '+str_ll(odd))

Comment: But I think the problem is result from the separate funciton.

Comment: Aside from the errors mentioned, you have a huge logic bug in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `separate` function is bad. You should initialize `T` and `F`, as otherwise one of them might not be defined when you try to return them. Also, you set `b` to a value but then use it as a second parameter for `LN`. I don't know what you're trying to do with `b`, so I just got rid of it for this simple solution:

```
def separate(ll, p):
    T = F = None
    while ll:
        a = ll.value
        if p(a):
            T = LN(a, T)
        else:
            F = LN(a, F)
        ll = ll.next
    return T, F
```

Comment: Oh I should initialize the T and F before the while loop. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, although that would only be a problem for your code if all list elements went into `T` or all went into `F`, which is not the case for your example. The problem you encountered is because of the `b` issue.

Comment: I actually didn't know that before. I did it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LN` constructor takes a value and a next node, but you're passing it two values.

Answer (score 0):

In an LN object, I think value was intended to be of type Integer and **next** to be of **type LN**. In seperate, you seem to have violated this contract in the assignment T = LN(a, b) where b can be an Integer. When this happens, Python tries to perform .value on the Integer and as a result raises an AttributeError.